# Arduino: Strange values from a int two dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, arduino, key-value-store

This should be pretty straight forward. I'm simply trying to call a two dimensional array in Arduino C*.

I'm used to using nested dictionaries and array in Python. I get it. But I don't get the expected value here. For instance, when I call the index say array[0][0], which is set to 2. I'm getting a value of like 5!

```
#include "SoftPWM.h"

int pins[5][3] = {
  { 0, 1, 2 },
  { 3, 4, 5 },
  { 6, 7, 8 },
  { 9, 10, 11 },
  { 12, 13, 13 }
};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SoftPWMBegin();
  for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
    for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
      SoftPWMSet(pins[1][p], 255);
    }
  }
  SoftPWMSetFadeTime(ALL, 100, 100);
}

void loop()
{
  for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
    Serial.print("l =");
    Serial.println(l);
    for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
      Serial.print("p =");
      Serial.println(p);
      Serial.print("pin =");
      Serial.println(pins[1][p]);

      SoftPWMSetPercent(pins[1][p], 100);
      delay(500);
      SoftPWMSetPercent(pins[1][p], 0);
      delay(500);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
l =0
p =0
pin =3 //<-- [0][0] should be 0
p =1
pin =4
p =2
pin =5   //<-- [0][2] should be 2
l =1
p =0
pin =3
p =1
pin =4
p =2
pin =5
l =2
p =0
pin =3   //<-- [2][0] should be 6
p =1
pin =4
p =2
pin =5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are printing `pins[1][p]`. Not `pins[l][p]`.

`pins[1][0]` is `3`. `pins[1][2]` is `5`.

Comment: Seriously? Hahaha! I guess that is what I get for using "l". If you take a look at the Arduino IDE: https://i.imgur.com/TAUzDTj.png There is almost no difference in those characters. Thanks alot!

Comment: @datguy.dev, the alot (a type of imaginary animal of course, since it's otherwise not an English word) says "you're welcome" (http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) :). Also, the best way to thank Kentaro Okuda is to upvote his answer and mark it as correct. Thank you.